# Embed PPT to HTML (for a webview in Android)

Tags: android, html, embed, powerpoint

Does anyone know a way to embed a PPT file (powerpoint) into a HTML?

I found solutions like embed through an iframe by Office Web App and/or Google Docs. I tried them and works fine into the HTML, but in my case I need to have the PPT file into a personal server.

Other options I found are like Embedit.in, a flash embed that shows th PPT (no convert the PPT to SWF (flash format)).

But, I still looking for a way for show a PPT file saved in a personal server into a HTML, any idea? any webservice for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Before PowePoint 2010 you could save the ppt to html using PowerPoint API.

Did you checked also for api vendors? It's a common issue probably there api to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion...

Convert the ppt to pdf and use the code generator @ http://pdfobject.com/generator.php .

Use standard (not java) .

There in one small mistake in the code they generate  Remove the hashtag **#** at the end of the url.

Comment: Note: It may be possible (but I doubt it) to embed a ppt with the same code, replacing type='application/pdf' with type='application/ppt'